# SetAdapter cannot be applied as the adapter of FirestoreRecyclerviewAdapter

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I am working on a chat app with firebase and I want to fitch the user information to the recyclerview...my code is correct by when I set the adapter to the recycler view its show an error.
Here is my code:

```
package com.abdelatif.chatapp;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder;

import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;


public class ChatFragment extends Fragment {

    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    ImageView mimageviewofuser;

    FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<FireBaseModel, NoteViewHolder> chatAdapter = null;

    RecyclerView mrecyclerview;



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.chatfragment,container,false);

        firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseFirestore= FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        mrecyclerview=v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);


        // Query query=firebaseFirestore.collection("Users");
        Query query=firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").whereNotEqualTo("uid",firebaseAuth.getUid());
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<FireBaseModel> allusername=new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<FireBaseModel>().setQuery(query,FireBaseModel.class).build();

        chatAdapter=new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<FireBaseModel, NoteViewHolder>(allusername) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NoteViewHolder noteViewHolder, int i, @NonNull FireBaseModel firebasemodel) {

                noteViewHolder.particularusername.setText(firebasemodel.getName());
                String uri=firebasemodel.getImage();

                Picasso.get().load(uri).into(mimageviewofuser);
                if(firebasemodel.getStatus().equals("Online"))
                {
                    noteViewHolder.statusofuser.setText(firebasemodel.getStatus());
                    noteViewHolder.statusofuser.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                }
                else
                {
                    noteViewHolder.statusofuser.setText(firebasemodel.getStatus());
                }

                noteViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "contactClicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });



            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public NoteViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

                View view=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_view_layout,parent,false);
                return new NoteViewHolder(view);
            }
        };

        mrecyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
        linearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(RecyclerView.VERTICAL);
        mrecyclerview.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        mrecyclerview.setAdapter(chatAdapter);
        chatAdapter.startListening();


        return v;

    }

    public class NoteViewHolder extends android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {

        private TextView particularusername;
        private TextView statusofuser;

        public NoteViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            particularusername=itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameOfUser);
            statusofuser=itemView.findViewById(R.id.statusOfUser);
            mimageviewofuser=itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewOfUser);
        }
    }
}
```

---

the error is in the line:  mrecyclerview.setAdapter(chatAdapter);

and the error is:
'setAdapter(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter)' in 'androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView' cannot be applied to '(com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<com.abdelatif.chatapp.FireBaseModel,com.abdelatif.chatapp.ChatFragment.NoteViewHolder>)'

---

I hope someone give me a solution...i searched many time but nothing.

Comment: Can you please check if the [following article helps you](https://medium.com/quick-code/display-data-from-firebase-firestore-in-android-recyclerview-db39f8c7d6b) and also can you please refer to the following documentations from [Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter) and [Firebase](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebaseui-android/firestore/readme/)?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you call `chatAdapter.startListening();` before calling `mrecyclerview.setAdapter(chatAdapter);`

Comment: Yeaah that's it bro it's soleved my problem..my fault is that i call it after setting the adapter...I understand....Thank you so much Charlie for answering me