# Fetching data from Firestore using FirestoreRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I started learning Firebase Firestore and this is my very first learning project.

In a tutorial that I'm following, the tutor uses `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter`, but in my code it's showing an error that I am using `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` instead of `Adapter`.

Error:

> at--------- recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter) commented errer ----------------------'setAdapter(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter)' in 'androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView' cannot be applied to '(com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<com.dharmik953.mynotes_firebase.firebaseModel,com.dharmik953.mynotes_firebase.HomePage.NoteViewHolder>)'

I don't know where the problem is, please help me to find it.

```
 FloatingActionButton addNotes;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager;
    FirebaseFirestore firestore;
    FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<firebaseModel,NoteViewHolder> adapter;
    FirebaseUser user;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);

        addNotes = findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setTitle("Notes");

        addNotes.setOnClickListener(v -> startActivity(new Intent(HomePage.this,addNotes.class)));

        Query query = firestore.collection("notes").document(user.getUid()).collection("myNotes").orderBy("title",Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<firebaseModel> userNotes = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<firebaseModel>().setQuery(query,firebaseModel.class).build();

        adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<firebaseModel, NoteViewHolder>(userNotes) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@android.support.annotation.NonNull @NonNull NoteViewHolder holder, int position, @android.support.annotation.NonNull @NonNull firebaseModel model) {
                holder.title.setText(firebaseModel.getTitle());
                holder.content.setText(firebaseModel.getContent());
            }

            @android.support.annotation.NonNull
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public NoteViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@android.support.annotation.NonNull @NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.notes_layout,parent,false);
                return  new NoteViewHolder(view);
            }
        };

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter); //here showing error --> 'setAdapter(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter)' in 'androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView' cannot be applied to '(com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<com.dharmik953.mynotes_firebase.firebaseModel,com.dharmik953.mynotes_firebase.HomePage.NoteViewHolder>)'

    }

    public class NoteViewHolder extends android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView title;
        private TextView content;
        LinearLayout layout;

        public NoteViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_title);
            content = itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_description);
            layout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Note);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello @Dharmik, can you also share the link to the tutorial you are following? Thanks

Comment: no at last i left the idea and tried to realtime database and it working fine. here is a link of tutorial     https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1tIj6UC0gcut51pibe8VRw4wauQRkEJJ

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SetAdapter cannot be applied as the adapter of FirestoreRecyclerviewAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69097047/setadapter-cannot-be-applied-as-the-adapter-of-firestorerecyclerviewadapter)

Comment: no it's not working